# Automapper - Error Updating Nested Child Collection

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel, automapper

I have an MVC 4 sample application using code first (POCO), EF, ViewModels and AutoMapper. I have created a controller where parent and corresponding child entities are on the same view (entity with nested collection of child entities).
Looks good so far except I am having problem with updating records. I am getting the following error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

I have been searching online for many days now trying out different solutions but couldn't get it working.

I have the following domain models:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

And corresponding viewmodels:

```
public class TeamVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PlayerVM> Players { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual TeamVM Team { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping is as follows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Player, PlayerVM>();
Mapper.CreateMap<PlayerVM, Player>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Team, TeamVM>();
Mapper.CreateMap<TeamVM, Team>();
```

My team controller edit action is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(TeamVM teamVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Team team = context.Teams.Find(teamVM.Id);
        Team updatedTeam = Mapper.Map<TeamVM, Team>(teamVM, team);
        context.Entry(team).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedTeam);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(teamVM);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

It's about the last part of the exception:

> or the unrelated object must be deleted

It looks like in your `Edit` method `Player`s are removed from `team.Players` (or maybe even cleared altogether because of copy failures). But, too bad, you can't just remove items from a child collection if the foreign key is not nullable (apparently, players can't exist without team). You have to remove the deleted players from the context.

So you must detect the players that are removed from the team and for each of them call

```
context.Players.Remove(player);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Gert. I'm not sure how Players get removed from the collection even without touching any player row when editing team records. I'm also not sure where and how to add that line of code you suggested to detect and delete removed players as I'm new to MVC. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you'll have to look in the debugger what happens to `team.Players` while you step through the `Edit` method.

Comment: I've been debugging and there's nothing there that suggests players are getting deleted. In fact the player count is consistent in both the domain and viewmodel objects.

Comment: From what I can see it must be something with `Player.TeamId`.

Comment: Could that be it? I'll have a look later. Thanks!

Comment: No, that's not it. I debugged and looks like there's no problem with Player.TeamId. I do have extra properties in the ViewModels for dropdownlists which I did not include in the above sample code for simplicity. I wonder if that's causing the problem: public int? RatingId, public virtual Rating Rating and public SelectList RatingList

Comment: Less likely because `RatingId` is nullable. Maybe the `Players` are overwritten by AutoMapper, giving EF the impression that they should be deleted _and_ created, while the count won't change.

Comment: You are probably right. Somewhere in the code players might be getting removed and placed back.